# How to specify a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to parse data from multiple workbooks with multiple worksheets into a single summary worksheet or workbook. So far I have been able to collect data from the specified cells, however I would like to include a range of cells for example ("A2:B20"). How can I specify this in looping process?

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetMyData()
Dim myDir As String, fn As String, sn As String, sn2 As String, n As    Long, NR As Long

'***** Change Folder Path *****
 myDir = "C:\attach"

 '***** Change Sheetname(s) *****
 sn = "Title"
 sn2 = "Monday"


fn = Dir(myDir & "\*.xlsx")
Do While fn <> ""
 If fn <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet10")
  NR = .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

  'Pick cells from worksheet "Title"
  With .Range("A" & NR)
    .Formula = "='" & myDir & "\[" & fn & "]" & sn & "'!B4"
    .Value = .Value
  End With
  With .Range("B" & NR)
    .Formula = "='" & myDir & "\[" & fn & "]" & sn & "'!B5"
    .Value = .Value
  End With
  With .Range("C" & NR)
    .Formula = "='" & myDir & "\[" & fn & "]" & sn & "'!B6"
    .Value = .Value
  End With
  With .Range("D" & NR)
    .Formula = "='" & myDir & "\[" & fn & "]" & sn & "'!B7"
    .Value = .Value
  End With
  With .Range("E" & NR)
    .Formula = "='" & myDir & "\[" & fn & "]" & sn & "'!A1"
    .Value = .Value
  End With
  With .Range("F" & NR)
    .Formula = "='" & myDir & "\[" & fn & "]" & sn & "'!A2"
    .Value = .Value
  End With
  'pick cells from worksheet "Monday"

  With .Range("G" & NR)
   .Formula = "='" & myDir & "\[" & fn & "]" & sn2 & Range("A1:C57")

  End With
End With
End If
fn = Dir
Loop
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet10").Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do Either

```
Col_1 = "A"
Col_2 = "B"
i = 2
j = 20
Range(Col_1 & i,Col_2 & j)
```

or

```
Col_1 = "A"
i = 2
j = 20
Range(Col_1 & i).Resize(j-i+1,2)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this, supposing you want a continuous range:

1. Pass that exact string to the `Range` function.  e.g. `Range("A3:C10")`
2. Pass the "first" cell as the first argument and the "last cell" as the second argument.  e.g. `Range("A3", "C10")`

Comment: Both of those options do not work.I get Type mismatch run-time error 13.

Comment: I beg to differ.  Type `Range("A1:B4").Formula = "= 1 + 5"` into the immediate window.  You'll find all cells in that range are assigned formula.  same for `Range("A1", "B4").Formula = "=1 + 5"`  If teasing out the correct string to input is difficult, maybe a different method of referencing the cells you want is in order.